# Including font-end javascript compiled from node module

Tags: node.js

I am playing with a node application, which is running a basic hello-world HTML page.

I want to use [isomerjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomer), which I installed via npm - though I imagine this question is more general than this one particular module. I do see it in the node_modules directory.

I'm not sure where to point my `<script src="/path/to/isomer.min.js"></script>` at. The module directory appears to only have the uncompiled files.

What is the accepted or standard way of utilizing front-end code from a node module? Am I missing a step?

Comment: Typically these purely front-end modules are bundled with the js source code for your websites with things like webpack, or your http server framework of choice (eg: express). Another option would be to copy those over to a public directory where files would be served as is and have clients request that through the `script` tag. But I'd recommend considering a cdn hosted version of the script since it seems like intended usage is not to download through npm.

Comment: I've looked a bit more into it, isomerjs is severely outdated, which is why I think it hasn't kept up as a proper node module, back then, modules weren't as well defined and it really shows, I think you should just give up on trying to install it with npm.